# How do I export my Mac profile as a zipped folder?

Tags: macos, backup

I have some typical photos, documents, etc. in various folders on my user profile on my Mac i.e. `/Users/thisisme/`. What is the easiest way to collect all of that data into one big zipped folder? I want to have a copy of all my folders / documents in that zip so I can save it to my Dropbox.

Comment: You could use the tar utility: https://superuser.com/questions/46512/create-a-tar-file-for-compressing-files-and-directories-on-mac-os-x

Comment: The other comment and answer posted so far (use tar or use zip) do answer your question. But, if you’re on a Mac, try some of Apple’s cloud tools, like iCloud and Cloud Photo Library. The former is best for backing up your files in real-time, no manual zipping required, and the latter specifically for your photos. You can also share some of your photo albums thru your Cloud Photo Library, if you or a friend/family want to access them from another Mac or a PC.

Comment: @jimtut Thanks for the suggestion! I usually would do that, but I'll be moving from Mac to a desktop. An archive of my old stuff would be the easiest way for me.

Comment: Understood. Zipping your home folder is not the best way to get all your photos though, if you’re using the Photos app. That app’s library has all your photos, and a LOT of other stuff, you don’t want a copy of its folder structure. Use the Photos app to do an Export (from the menu, or just drag photos out) and make a new folder with all your photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you called your "profile" is properly known as your "home directory".

You can make a `.zip` compressed archive of any folder, including your home directory, by selecting it in the Finder and then selecting `File > Compress "foldername"`. ("foldername" will be replaced by the name of whatever folder is currently selected in the active Finder window.)

That command also appears in the contextual menu you get by right-clicking, two-finger-clicking, or control-clicking on a folder.